# Get a slice of data in Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to construct some app for time schedules of public transport. Most it is pretty easy, but my idea was to show only some slice of it according to the current time.

I have pretty unfriendly XML-feed from official and the schedule data presented in it looks like this:

```
<day day="31">
  <hour hr="6">
    <minutes>04</minutes>
    <minutes>44</minutes>
  </hour>
  <hour hr="7">
    <minutes>08</minutes>
    <minutes>51</minutes>
  </hour>

  […]

</day>
<day day="96">
  <hour hr="6">
    <minutes>06</minutes>
  </hour>
  <hour hr="7">
    <minutes>47</minutes>
  </hour>
  <hour hr="9">
    <minutes>59</minutes>
  </hour>

  […]

</day>
```

Well, the first thing I should say, that this `day` tag do not means a specific day of the month or similar, it is identifies (some how, I really not sure why 31 and 96) is it working day or weekend (sat, sun). Also there could be only one, ie. for working days or for everyday(`<day day="127">`).

It is universal actual schedule, it can have only one or two different schedules for "working days ()", "each days ()" and "working days ()" + "weekends ()". That's it. No dates. Only numerical identifiers "31", "96" and "127".

So I'm trying to collect this data and to slice closest 5 time entries from that data corresponding to the current time. So I have two questions: what would be the best way to store this data for processing and how do I process the data to get 5 entries but remember that if today will not be any more transport or less then 5 it should iterate tomorrow's schedule depending on day (working day or weekend).

There is no problem to parse the XML. But the problem is how to parse it in most effective structure.

As the result I plan to get something like:

```
18:30, 19:30, 20:30, 21:40, tomorrow 6:50
```

Hope you've got me right. I'm not waiting for solutions, only advice. I can write everything by myself. Only need is concept.

Comment: What have you tried so far? To do the nearest-5 slice, you'd have to find the one node that's CLOSEST to the current date/time, then simply grab the 5 nearest siblings.

Comment: This is almost correct. I did so almost exactly as you're saying. But. I want that it to get the time even if it will be tomorrow. Imagine: there is a bus with two schedules — for working days and for weekend, and today is Friday and according to data there only four buses left today, so I want that it show me also tomorrow first bus. But tomorrow is Saturday, so it has different schedule.

Comment: XPath's next-/previous-sibling works across tree branches, so once you know which node is closest to the time you're interested in, it's simple to get the 5 nearest nodes as well.

Comment: And what about "next day — Saturday"? And how do I consider on which schedule to select? Look at the XML sample, please.

Comment: If the xml has the full year-long schedule, just look for a node that has day/hour/min/sec closest to your desired time. If Today/Friday is day 200, then next day/saturday would be day 201.

Comment: No, it has not. It is universal actual schedule, it can have only one or two different schedules for "working days (`<day day="31" />`)", "each days (`<day day="127" />`)" and "working days  (`<day day="31" />`)" + "weekends  (`<day day="96" />`)". That's it. No dates. Only numerical identifiers "31", "96" and "127".

Comment: So is day=31 actually Jan 31? how does that number translate back to a calendar date?

Comment: No, it is not. Actually, I do not know why it is 31, 96 and 127. It does not corresponds to any dates. Only to week days (somehow). This why I'm asking for help cause I believe that misunderstanding of that is the main problem in this issue. May be the audience would have some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are "PHP-XML Parsers" but I don't know any to vouch for. You can write your own (not that hard just tedious) using PHP's [xml_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php)

Create an array that's comfortable for you to work with, such as

```
$bus[year][month][day][hour][minute] = true;
```

Looping through that, will give you what you want.

Good Luck!

---

As per your comments, if you have an array:

```
$bus[0] = 364; // 6:04 am
$bus[1] = 404; // 6:44 am
```

Then you can find the closest value by looping through. Keep track of the index, and display 5 indecies prior to that.

---

Here's quick, dirty, unoptimized, don't use this example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$friday = array(300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000);
$saturday = array(320,420,520,620,720,820,920,1020);

$schedule = array(0 => $M, $T, $W, $T, $friday, $saturday, $S);

$dayNumber = 4;
$time = 720; // noon

$shown = 0;
foreach ($schedule[$dayNumber] as $hm) {
        if ($hm > $time) {
                $hour = floor($hm / 60);
                $minute = $hm - ($hour*60);
                echo "$hour:$minute, ";
                $shown++;
        }
        if ($shown == 5) break;
}

if ($shown < 5) {
        $time = 0;
        echo 'Or tomorrow: ';
        foreach ($schedule[$dayNumber + 1] as $hm) {
                if ($hm > $time) {
                        $hour = floor($hm / 60);
                        $minute = $hm - ($hour*60);
                        echo "$hour:$minute, ";
                        $shown++;
                }
                if ($shown == 5) break;
        }

}
?>
```

output:

```
13:20, 15:0, 16:40, Or tomorrow: 5:20, 7:0,
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough: the schedule is repeated, it is universal for everyday except it can differs for week days. So, no need to set it for each specific date. Also it is not problem for parsing: I can get something like `[0 => '6:04', 1 => '6:44' …]` or similar with no problems. The question is how to store it according to week days so iterate it correctly for that slice.

Comment: Don't think about "how to easily store it"; think about "how will it be easy to use". For example if you convert hour and minute to (hour*60 + minute)  after you sort it - you will have in-order timestamps

Comment: And what about "next day — Saturday"? And how do I consider on which schedule to select? Look at the XML sample, please.

Comment: For simplicity you could store all 7 schedules, even if 5 of them are identical. Anything from "next day" would always be the earliest in the day, so key 0

Comment: I've added a fully working example. You can wrap parts of the code in a function to make it cleaner, and auto-check for wrap-around days, like Sunday + 1 = Monday. Use a modulus `%`.

Comment: Ok, this could work even if there is some double code, but, are you serious about to store schedule for each day separately? There is usually could be 5-7 stops with up to some 10 routes on the page load, and each schedule could have some 100 entries. It won't be kind productive to load such amount of data even if I cache it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4453/discussion-between-mikhail-and-yuri)